# C# get text from .txt file that's added to the program

Tags: c#, string, file, stream

In my project i added a `.txt` file. I need to get the content inside of it, line after line, and slip the lines. I alreaddy have code to slipt the lines and overall handle the content of the `.txt` file like i want to, ill i need is to acess the content of the added file.

The code i have to handle the text form a txt file in the computer:

```
public static string[] loc_file = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\loc.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
        public static string loc_up = string.Join("|", loc_file);
        public static string[] loc_p = loc_up.Split('|');
        public static string[] loc = loc_p.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray<string>();
        public static string[] loc_txt = loc_p.Where((c, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToArray<string>();
```

now, how i think the code for what i need will be:

```
public string exePath = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\loc.txt";
Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(namexe);
        string[] a = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        File.WriteAllBytes(exePath, bytes);
```

and then just read the text from the file.

thanks!

EDIT 1:
im making this code on my own, not sure if it will work but ill post annyways, if it ends out working i might be helping someone:

```
        public bool get_file(string file)
    {
        string filePath = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + file;
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            try
            {
                Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
                string[] a = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
                return true;
            }
            catch { return false; }
        }
        else { return false; }
    }
```

EDIT 2:
I just realized that `string filePath = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + file;
            if (File.Exists(filePath))`
will give me error because there is no file at the strat of the , lets call it cycle. So ill remove the part to see if file exists cause it makes no sence, leaving the code to be:

```
        public bool get_file(string file)
    {
        string filePath = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + file;
        try
        {
            Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file);
            string[] a = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
```

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: much appreciated!